# Best way to host a web page showing details from multiple servers vb.net asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, web-services

I have 2 servers that produce xml files and store them locally on their hard drives.

Im not to sure what would be the best way to make these details viewable from any machine on the same network?

I have created a asp.net web page which reads and displays the xml files. It does it fine locally, but would i have to host it on a dedicated web facing server so that it could display information from the 2 different servers on the network?

Answer (score 0):

does not need to be internet facing if all servers on same network.

You have not given much details but you could access using network shares if that works better for you.  You are also using windows so if you wanted you would sync the files so the both or one server had both files (DFS).

More details - better answers :-)